# How to make 1 figure on the left and 2x2 figures on the right?

Tags: floats

I have five figures. I want to put 1 figure on the left and the rest of the four figures on the right in the format of 2x2. Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives using the `subcaption` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.525\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{}\label{subfig:key-a}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{subfig:key-b}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{subfig:key-c}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{subfig:key-d}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{subfig:key-e}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{shared caption for all 5 images}
  \label{fig:example-key}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.575\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{caption for the image in the left}\label{fig:left}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.375\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{subfig:key-a1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{subfig:key-b1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{subfig:key-c1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
      \caption{}\label{subfig:key-d1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{shared caption for the 4 images on the right}
    \label{fig:key-right}
  \end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting the images inside `tabular`s allows for easy stacking as well as vertical alignment using optional arguments (`[t]`op or `[b]`ottom).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ c }
    \includegraphics[width=.29\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}%
  \begin{tabular}{ c c }
    \includegraphics[width=.29\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[width=.29\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
    \includegraphics[width=.29\linewidth]{example-image-c} &
      \includegraphics[width=.29\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also You can use `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
\center{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a.png} A)}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.47\linewidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}} a)\\
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.47\linewidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}} \\ b)
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.47\linewidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}} c) \\
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.47\linewidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}} d) \\
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```